# What is the meaning of the reader in this sentence ?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033870/synopsis)

> When Cairo and Brigid O'Shaughnessy meet, they make references that
>   the **reader** and Spade don't initially comprehend.

What is the meaning of the **reader** in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

Although your source is a review of the film based upon Dashiell Hammett's novel *The Maltese Falcon*, for some reason the reviewer, in this sentence, writes as if the novel, and not the film, is the subject of the review. **The reader** in this sentence refers to *the person who is reading the novel*. The reveiwer should have written **the audience** instead.

Note that reviews at IMDB.com are written without any editorial supervision. Anyone at all can write and publish a review there, and their work should not necessarliy be taken as exemplars of proper grammar or usage.